# Java: How to detect the value of an element in an array changes?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Using Intellij IDEA, we can easily detect change of a field by using field breakpoint. However, if I have an array of int `int[] array = new int[5]` and I want to stop whenever the program changes `array[2]`. Can I do it with Intellij IDEA?

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-field-watchpoints.html

Comment: No. It's about field breakpoint and I knew that. Field breakpoint can only detect the change of the variable `array`, e.g., firstly `int[] array=new int[5];` then `array=new int[3]`. In this case breakpoint will hit. However, what I want is stopping when `array[2]` change.

Comment: ah, so when an index changes

Comment: Check conditional debug in intellij

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible in IntelliJ IDEA (or any other Java IDE/debugger as far as I know).

[JDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html#interfaces) allows to set watchpoints for fields and since the field doesn't change when the element of the array is modified, it will not trigger. There is no API to set watchpoints to individual array elements.